# SQL Selecting less significant entity from table

Tags: oracle10g

I have a problem with some query from given result set i need to select the less detail row from table under some conditions.

I have three selects that after union return this table

```
SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 1 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 1
UNION
SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 2 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 2
UNION
SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 3 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 3
```

The result can be something like this

```
1000 100 1
1000 200 2
1000 300 3
```

From this table the final result should be 1000 100 1

The best case scenario is when a value is found then is no longer searched in next select.

Some ideas ?

EDIT:

The solution presented by 'Jeffrey Kemp' one query works fine.

```
1000 100 1
1000 200 2
1000 300 3
1001 200 2
1001 300 3
```

result

```
   1000 100 1 
   1001 200 2
```

Database: Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your query, this is one option to consider:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 1 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 1
      UNION
      SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 2 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 2
      UNION
      SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 3 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 3
   )
   ORDER BY 3
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

An alternative is to add conditions to the queries to determine if they need to run at all:

```
SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 1 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 1
UNION
SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 2 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 1)
UNION
SELECT A_ID, B_ID, 3 FROM MY_TABLE JOIN MY_TABLE2 ON SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 1)
AND   NOT EXISTS (SPECIFIC CONDITION FOR LEVEL 2)
```

Of course, I don't know the nature of your "specific conditions" so I don't know if this will work for you or not.

Comment: Your answer is correct for my question, but would not work for my over all case where i need to have in result not single entity but a set. But still is same approach that I used.

Comment: BTW note that the `UNION` s could be changed to `UNION ALL` here, since the results are guaranteed unique anyway. This might even improve performance somewhat.